# Is there a way to access Java classes that are not the main method through node.js?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I need to access a Java algorithm through node.js that encrypts an image to `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`. I tried recreating the logic in node.js but there are certain libraries that can only be found in Java

I can't make changes to the .jar file, I can only call it's methods.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd be surprised if equivalent function is not available in crypto, crypto-js, NPM or elsewhere.

Comment: Make your own jar that interfaces with the jar you have through command line arguments

Comment: I hope you know that Java and Javascript are extremely different languages.

Comment: Yes, I do know that Java and Javscript are extremely different, I'm just trying to call a .jar file through node for it's logic. I did try crypto, crypto-js, and forge. What I first need is to make an image into bytes. I can't find the equivalent javascript of Files.readAllBytes()

Comment: You're unable to find a JavaScript feature to read the bytes of a file? How about `fs.readFile()` or `fs.readFileSync()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just figured how to do it. So we you can use node-jre and use that to call the .jar file by setting the jar path and the main class

I had to make changes in the original .jar file and add a main class to call it

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible to communicate from nodejs code base to jar file. if you want to encrypt an image below modules will help.
1.node-file-encrypt - npm
2.file-encryptor - npm
3. crypto

Comment: While you can't natively incorporate a JAR into a Node.js application, you can certainly invoke a Java application from Node.js. Whether or not it's advisable is another question.